# How to call a wcf service without adding service reference at design time

Tags: c#, wcf, url, reference

I am trying to call a service written in c# language as a WCF project of .net .
 The IP of the host will change time by time. I need to call the service without adding the service reference to the client at design time so that I can change it later without compiling the client application. 
 I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic) article from code project but when I publish my client I do not have any config file to change the url in it.
 Can anyone help me to find how to change the URL of the web service at run time without recompiling the client application 
 best regards

Comment: You can change the endpoint without recompiling anyway, it's configurable.

Comment: The article you reference is for ASMX web services, which **are not** WCF.  There are simliarities, as WCF is the replacement for legacy ASMX.  I can think of a couple of ways to do what you want to in WCF via code, but the question is how are you going to supply the service address to the client if you don't have a config file?  In other words, if you're not using a config file, what are you using that won't require you to rebuild your client project when the service address changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple way to do what I wanted to do.
 I found many pages in the internet addressing the .config file but I was not able to find the file. 
 This is the way that I solved my problem:

there is a .config file in the project solution in the visual studio. If the address in this file is correct then the published program will not look for any other file such as .config file to get the address of the service. so I changed the address specified in the app.config file in the project solution to a nonsense address.
 Then without publishing the project, I only pressed f6 to refresh the related file to the project.
 I moved to the path where my project is saved. For me it is: C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\my project
 Then I moved to bin directory and then debug directory
 Here I found the .exe file of my solution and a .config file which is the right file that I was looking for.
 I copied the .exe and .config file in another directory. Now when I run the .exe file it will look to the .config file that I copied just beside it. If the address of the web service in the .config file is correctly defined then I can access the methods in the web service from this client.

I wish it will also help others who are looking for addressing web service from an external file without recompiling the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Grant said above, as long as the service contracts don't change, you can change the endpoint address without recompiling the application itself.

Check your solution explorer for a file called App.config. (It may be called Web.config if you're making some kind of web app.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working copy. For me it works fine and returns List

```
private List<MyClass> GetAllSiteDetailsJSON(string language)
{

   Uri address = 
        new Uri(@"http://weburlpath/MyService/MyService.svc/GetAllList/"
                                                               + language);
   HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
   request.Method = "GET";
   request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

   using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
   {
       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
       string jSon = reader.ReadToEnd();
       reader.Close();

       JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       List<MyClass> result = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(jSon);
       return result;
   }
}
```

And Here is the class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```